# How asp.net use <% %> server tag in Response.Write?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

How asp.net use <% %> server tag in Response.Write ?
I tried the below :

```
Response.Write("<% MyCode %>")
```

but this code prints <% MyCode %> as a text

Comment: Thats pointless, either use `Response.Write` or (on aspx) inline asp tags, not both. However, what are you trying at all? Maybe there is a best third option. Don't write ASP with ASP.NET, learn how to use webcontrols.

Comment: `Resonse.Write` doesn't use server tags. It just prints out the string *verbatim* to the HTML output. It doesn't do any processing or encoding, it just writes the string on the output stream, nothing more. There's no point for it to handle server tags - you're already in server code, why would you want it to evaluate random strings as if they *could* contain server code? At the very least, that would be an awful security hole, and a significant performance setback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response. Write is a method that outputs some string to response output. If you wish to have some custom logic just place your logic in <% %>.

`<% /* Some code */ %>` is probably what you want.

`<% Response.Write("some string") %>` equals `<%=some string %>`